# Dictionary within Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

I am creating A Dictionary which has a key as Dictionary.
Here is the declaration of both dictionaries.

```
Dictionary<Dictionary<Int64,string>, Int64> AccountTypeDic = new Dictionary<Dictionary<Int64, string>, Int64>();
Dictionary<Int64,string> IdName = new Dictionary<Int64,string>();
```

Now when I'm trying to add data into Dictionary I'm getting exception.

Execption: An item with the same key has already been added.
So please tell me how should I add data into Dictionary.

```
if (sqlDataReader.HasRows)
{
    while (sqlDataReader.Read())
    {
        IdName.Clear();
        IdName.Add(Int64.Parse(sqlDataReader["ID"].ToString()), 
           sqlDataReader["ACCOUNT_NAME"].ToString());
        AccountTypeDic.Add(IdName,
           Int64.Parse(sqlDataReader["SEQUENCE_ID"].ToString()));
    }
}
```

sqlDataReader has all the fields ID, Account Name and Sequence Code.

Please don't suggest me that I should use some other data structures. I just want to know how it can be handled in this way.

Comment: > don't suggest me that I should use some other data structures - note, that according to MSDN, `Dictionary.GetHashCode` is inherited from `System.Object`. Thus, it is a very, very bad choice for the key.

Comment: I won't suggest other data structures, but I do want to say that if your goal is to make ID and Account name together the key of a dictionary, there are better ways to associate them together than as the key and value in another dictionary.  But you are of course always free to do whatever works for your situation.

Comment: Shouldn't you have Int64 as key instead of a Dictionary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you are attempting to add the same key over and over again here:

```
while (sqlDataReader.Read())
{
    IdName.Clear();
    IdName.Add(Int64.Parse(sqlDataReader["ID"].ToString()),sqlDataReader["ACCOUNT_NAME"].ToString());
    AccountTypeDic.Add(IdName, Int64.Parse(sqlDataReader["SEQUENCE_ID"].ToString()));
}
```

Your `IdName` instance is ALWAYS the same. So make sure you have different instances as keys. Basically the `IdName` dictionary should be declared and instantiated inside your while loop:

```
while (sqlDataReader.Read())
{
    long id = sqlDataReader.GetInt64(sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("ID"));
    string accountName = sqlDataReader.GetString(sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("ACCOUNT_NAME"));
    long sequenceId = sqlDataReader.GetInt64(sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("SEQUENCE_ID"));

    var idName = new Dictionary<long, string>();
    idName.Add(id, accountName);

    // Make sure that here you don't have repetitions of idName
    // or the next line will bomb with the exact same exception
    AccountTypeDic.Add(idName, sequenceId);
}
```

> Please don't suggest me that I should use some other data structures.

That's exactly what everybody will suggest you when we see this *thing*. I have seen people using dictionaries as values, but dictionaries as keys for another dictionary, oh well.

Comment: Calling  `Clear()` methode and instanting new instance isn't same?

Comment: No, of course not. Calling the .Clear method simply removes all values of the `IdName` dictionary instance. But it absolutely doesn't change the instance on which you are calling this method. In order to change an instance you need to call the constructor. That's what creates a new instance of a given type in .NET.